# Basic Regex information

Tags: regex

Where can I find basic information on Regex?  My textbook does not explain it very well.

Answer (score 4):

- http://www.regular-expressions.info/
- http://www.cheat-sheets.org/#RegularExpressions
- http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp
- http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html

Comment: Also the regular expression library [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) was fun.

Answer (score 0):

[perldoc perlrequick](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html)

[perldoc perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a tutorial some time ago.  Here's the link:
http://tech.bluesmoon.info/2006/04/beginning-regular-expressions.html

Answer (score 0):

A couple of books,

[The AWK Programming Language - Aho, Kernighan, Weinberger](http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/awkbook/index.html)
[Mastering Regular Expressions - Jeffrey Friedl](http://regex.info/)

and a paper.

[Regular Expression Matching Can Be Simple And Fast (but is slow in Java, Perl, PHP, Python, Ruby, ...)](http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to find tools to help with regex pattern matching as well, the best one I've found is here:

http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/desktop/

And it's completely free.  It also has some examples to help you, too.  Hope this helps!